# Firebase Messaging Can't Send - How to get an OAuth Bearer Token using .Net or JavaScript?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been following the Firebase Messaging tutorial for a while trying to get notifications to work in a basic .Net Core app using JavaScript with ServiceWorker before I try to implement it in my main app. I'm failing at posting a message using jQuery's post with a response of `401 - "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential` and a status of `unauthenticated`.

The bearer token is the reason because I'm using the same one as in the tutorial and this took me a while to realize because I cannot find any explanation of what this token is or that I needed my own, the tutorial seems to skip that part. After exhaustive browsing through Google docs I have found this, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server?authuser=0 which is what the person who commented below has shared. It is exactly what is needed, problem is that it's done in Node. For those who don't use Node, can't do anything with it. Luckily right above Google states that we can use our preferred language using the [Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/?authuser=0), except again I'm met with an exhaustive search. The same methods used in the Node example don't seem to be in the [Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/?authuser=0) and the single example shown for each language is how to get a token to use with a Google service like the People service and getting access to a users information. I don't see how that can be translated to getting an OAuth bearer token to authenticate with FCM so notifications can be sent. I've tried many combinations and I don't see any documentation showing what methods are available to find any similar methods that are being used in the Node example.

I just need a bearer token for below. Does anyone know how to get a bearer token for usage with FCM using either .Net or JavaScript like the Google doc says you can do?

```
$.post({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/floridarecycling-b91ec/messages:send",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA'
        },
        data: {
            "message": {
                "token": "my device token",
                "notification": {
                    "body": "This is an FCM notification message!",
                    "title": "FCM Message",
                }
            }
        },
        success: function () { console.log("Success") },
        error: function (err) { console.log("error ", err) }
    });

$.post({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/floridarecycling-b91ec/messages:send",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {
            "message": {
                "token": "my device id",
                "notification": {
                    "body": "This is an FCM notification message!",
                    "title": "FCM Message",
                }
            }
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA')
        },
        success: function () { console.log("Success") },
        error: function (err) { console.log("error ", err) }
    });
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://medium.com/@ThatJenPerson/authenticating-firebase-cloud-messaging-http-v1-api-requests-e9af3e0827b8) will help

Comment: It has helped, I'm stuck on the part where I need to access the auth API. I'm not using angular so the code `var {google} = require(‘googleapis’);` that gets access to the API isn't going to work for me. I'm unsure of the equivalent `<script>` tag that I can include to get access to the same tools to try and get a bearer token.

Comment: Omg I just realized that you are THE @JenPerson who wrote it! Wow! I just tweeted you because you said it was ok at the end of your post. Great post btw it does very much help! If I can just get the equivalent `<script>`. Thank you for the post.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of use don't use Node. The doc here, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server?authuser=0, shows that we can use our preferred language. But there's nothing there about how that is done with our preferred language, unless you need to use the people API and register a person. I just need to register my app not using Node.

Comment: perhaps something here could help https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User#getidtoken

Comment: @jimmont Unfortunately that is for a User. A gets a token for the current user. When working with FCM you're not requesting a JWT for a specific user. I'll confirm that this method truly won't work but if it requires a user then it most likely won't.